# Is there a way to detect if my hand is open or closed with the Kinect SDK?

Tags: c#, kinect

I would like to be able to detect if my hand is open or closed using the Kinect SDK.
I don't need any individual finger tracking just open or closed is good enough, any suggestions?

Cheers 
/Jimmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, NO.

But you could do a workaround yourself. Track the distance between wrist and hand, combine it with the depth data, and check how far from the centre of your hand, the depth stays the same (following the same angle as wrist-hand has)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out http://candescentnui.codeplex.com/. With that you can do quite a bit more than checking whether your hand is open or not.

Answer (score 2):

The newer Kinect SDK 2.0 has a HandState struct which now tracks whether a hand is closed or open.

```
HandState rightHand = HandState_Unknown;
bodies[i]->getHandState(&rightHand); //bodies would be an IBody* array
```

Comment: I know this question is old, but I wished to update this question. (From what I know as a SO newbie, this is alright . . . )